# Embed Soundcloud repost feed on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, embed, soundcloud

Soundcloud provides a way for developers to embed playlists and tracks easily in Wordpress. Is there a way to embed my reposts in the site so visitors can see my feed of reposted tracks?